# django-allauth: social login merged with existing local user account

Tags: django, django-allauth

First, I am new to OAuth and django-allauth, so if I am asking silly questions, please forgive me. I found several question on this topic, but no answers that I fully understood, so I am hoping to get some help here.

The app is for a school I am associated with and as such, it will not be open to just anyone creating an account. Because the school uses google for their login to all the school systems, I really just need to accept any social login from the domain and have it automatically create an account.

However, since I am using a custom user model with email as the identifying field and I have added some additional fields that need to be filled in by the admin, what I was thinking is the following:

1. I import a CSV file of all the allowable students along with the extra information associated with them. In this process, I create a local user account with a password that the student does not know, and is not told.
2. On the login page, instead of asking them to login with their local credentials, what I want to do is to only present the option of using their Google email address to authenticate. When they do this, I want to create a social login and associate it with their local account based on email address. If no local account exists, then it should reject them and tell them to see the administrator to be added to the system.

As a newbie, I have been struggling with this for some time. Here is what I have so far:

> settings.py

```
...
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',    # existing backend
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
# ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'student_track.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"  #later change to mandatory
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'student_track.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True

# ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'student_track.adapters.SocialLoginAdapter'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

> urls.py

```
...
# access project, plus allauth urls
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
...
```

> /templates/account/login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load socialaccount %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                Welcome!, please sign in using your school email to use this application.
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form class="login" method="post" action="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button class=" btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit"><img width="20px"
                                                                         style="margin-bottom:3px; margin-right:5px"
                                                                         alt="Google sign-in"
                                                                         src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"/>
                    Login with Google
                </button>
            </form>


        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

> /templates/account/logout.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <p>{% trans 'Are you sure you want to sign out?' %}</p>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if redirect_field_value %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
        {% endif %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans 'Sign Out' %}</button>
         <a class="btn btn-danger btn-block" href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">{% trans 'Cancel' %}</a>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Where I am stuck is that I don't fully understand where/how to only allow social logins from a specific domain, and before authenticating to match it to a local user account.

It looks like I should be doing this in the pre_social_login() method, but honestly I don't understand where / how to do this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!!!!